# How do I make leather tires for a bicycle?

Tags: technology, transportation

In my world, bicycles are metal frames with leather tires.  How would I make a leather tire?  I am planning to use buffalo leather and waterproof it a lot.  I would give it traction with some sort of heavy duty rope.
An additional question, how much weight could a leather tire support?  Could it haul a family in a wagon or some heavier metals, or would it need to be for smaller loads?

My village makes the tires locally.  It's one of their trade goods.  They live in North America, on lake Superior.  Their world has trade goods for metal, cloth, wood, animal products, and a few other things.  Access to rubber is a thing of the long past for them.

Comment: Rubber comes from latex which comes from trees. They have no access to latex trees? Wood comes from trees and they have that. I think the reason wood wheels existed but not leather is because you can't really. Do they need to be pneumatic? Also, you do not need pneumatic tires for a wagon. There are other forms of suspension which don't need tires.

Comment: Also, wheels only need traction if they are being driven like a car or bike rear wheel, but not on something like a wagon being pulled.

Comment: If you mean a pneumatic leather tire, it seems doubtful that leather would successfully contain any significant air pressure.  A solid tire might work using specially treated leather known as "sole leather", known as far back as the Roman Empire, but would probably still wear quickly and the rope would wear away almost immediately.  (Bicycles have high https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_pressure) Your villagers would be better off creating iron-banded or completely wooden wheels instead, similar to the early velocipede bicycles; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocipede.

Comment: I know it's not what you're aiming for, but people have ridden on bicycles with wooden tires for a long time. During the 2nd world war in the Netherlands the Germans confiscated many rubber tired bicycles, so many started to use wooden wheels again. As an alternative you could make the tires with just many layers of leather, making it a solid but flexible (more than wood anyway) tire.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? you just selectively breed cows for intestines of the required gauge & superior wear characteristics to normal cow intestines. :))

Comment: Why use leather at all, when you are already planning to use rope? Just use a mixed metal/textile rope. So metal to the outside for durability textile to he core for some shock absorbancy.  Of course making metal rope is not easy.

Answer (score 6):

No problem

As seen in the [history of tires](https://www.treadwright.com/blogs/treadwright-blog/the-history-of-tires), leather was historically used as the tread surface for wheels, in very similar situations where a metal band was normally used.
The leather provides a much gentler ride, but it does wear out much more quickly than a steel band would.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Tires don't require air**

Tires come in many forms, as just a shape and function is required. Assuming that @GrumpyYoungMan is correct, you can't use air inside the tires. Air is only one way to soften blows of irregular ground though. You can make the leather tire solid. With many ways to change the strength and consistency of the leather you can simply layer it into a tire shape with different limitations in mind (cart vs bicycle). With a rope exterior it's likely protected against many piercing and scratching damage as well. It'll likely be less effective than current air tires, but for a leather tire it's probably the pinnacle of comfort.

Answer (score 1):

On our earth they made leather in cords, round in cross section up to about 1 cm (just under half an inch) in diameter in my experience, by rolling thin leather and glueing or sewing it in place.

I can see that done in bigger sizes, up to the sizes needed for a light bicycle. 'Solid' leather will never be as hard as solid wood or iron 'tires', but will not last as long on stones and grit of normal road surfaces of pre-tarmac roads.

You can add an extra leather skin on the outside, of a harder kind of leather, which is much more sturdy against the rough road surfaces.
It will still be much less sturdy than the 21st century bicycle tires.
Remember that leather is an expensive, in growing the animals and in the work needed to prepare the skins and tan them, and people will likely not spoil it on tires which will wear out in a short time, or only those who are very rich.

I guess you will be better off to use hard cycle tires and more springs in your bikes, but that would not be as much of a trade item for your village.

Handmade or simple machinery rope is also expensive and new rope will not be used as tires. But old rope will be available, as natural fiber ropes will wear out in parts while other parts will still have some life in them. Those parts will likely be available for tires, but only when available.